# Palatisation in “liked your”

Tags: palatalization

We can palatise *don't you* or *what ya* (as in *What ya doing?*), but it doesn't apply to *liked your*.

I was thinking that palatisation occurs in the first two since there's a voiced sound before the *t* unlike *liked your*.

Comment: *liked your* can become *like chur* ( sounds like *lecture* but with the *like* vowel.)  ?

Comment: Voicing doesn't really matter. Palatalization can work on both vd and vl consonants. Any consonant from dental back to velar can palatalize, though the speed and context vary a lot. Most English palatalization produces CH or J sounds, occasionally SH with fricatives. Oh, and who says it doesn't apply to "liked your"?

Comment: Your question isn't specific enough as the answer depends on what accent of English you're speaking in.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman The question is perfectly specific enough as is because palatalization occurs in all English dialects, doncha know.

Comment: I assume you're talking about yod-coalescence? That certainly does occur in *liked your.*